# Change rosconsole minimum log level

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm debugging a ROS node and I'm trying to find an easy way to change the output level of rosconsole so I can see the debug statements, but I'm not seeing much. I've seen something about changing the log4j configuration file, but this seems obtuse. There are ROS environmental variables for just about everything else - is there nothing for easily changing verbosity?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260819/change-rosconsole-minimum-log-level/) by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like there has been discussion about this previously, see [this issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/394). Looks like the end decision was "open to implementation", but it might environment variables in general might not be sufficiently clean.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0